# Why can't I push variable content on stack successfully?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data
msg db 'enter number ',10,0
output db '%hd',0

section .bss
val resw 1

section .text
global main

extern printf 
extern scanf

main :
  push msg 
  call printf 
  add esp,4
  push val  
  push output
  call scanf 
  add esp,8
  ;movzx eax,word[val]
  ;push eax
  push word[val]
  push output
  call printf 
  add esp,8
ret
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Select the code and click the `{}` button to make it formatted as code. Then add a detailed explanation what you tried to do and what the problem is.

Comment: While you do have a question in your title, your code has absolutely no explanation with it. What makes you think that you aren't able to push something onto the stack? Is your code failing in some way? What is your expected outcome? Are there assembler errors? What are they? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: The calling convention mandates arguments be pushed using multiples of 32 bits. If you really want you can adjust `esp` by `2` before you do the `push` and that will work but is not recommended.

Comment: above code should simply print entered value. instead that i am getting segmentation fault (core dump). but if i first move value into register and then stack then its printing fine.  why ?  how to push directly from memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> push word[val]
> ```

This only pushes a word and you need to have a dword on the stack.
You can do it like:

```
xor ax,ax
push ax           ;Gives a high word of zero, much like your MOVZX did.
push word[val]
```

Your segmentation fault comes from the fact that you pushed a total of 6 bytes but removed a total of 8 bytes through `add esp,8`.

Comment: i only changed     add esp,8  to     add esp,6   . and I am getting correct output. Is it good practice o r should i do above mentioned method  of xor ax......?

Comment: @matheromqq Misaligning the stack to a boundary not evenly divisible by 4 before a function call is **not** a good practice in 32-bit code and against the [System V 32-bit ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf). In this document _WORD_ refers to 4-bytes (32-bit value). It says _Argument words are pushed onto the stack in reverse order (that is, the
rightmost argument in C call syntax has the highest address), **preserving the
stack’s word alignment**. All incoming arguments appear on the stack, residing
in the stack frame of the caller._

Comment: @matheromqq: you could also `push word 0` to generate `66 6a 00`, a 16bit `push imm`.  Or push `ax` without zeroing it, since the ABI doesn't require the padding to be zero, IIRC.  But I'd recommend `movzx` / `push`, because `push [mem]` is a 2-uop instruction already.  You're about to call a function which will clobber all the call-clobbered registers, so there can't be register pressure.